# how to adding new tab in readline python

Tags: python, readlines

I have a problem can't adding a new tab in reading file.
I've tried readline, but I am confused..

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
count = 0
for i in f.readlines():
     count += 1
     if count == 3:
          #adding new tab
     print i,
```

In here, I have `data.txt` which contains data like this:

```
af  Afrikaans
sq  Albanian
ar  Arabic
hy  Armenian
az  Azerbaijani
eu  Basque
```

But I can't adding new tab if the data is in a certain count readline.
I want to make it like this..

```
af  Afrikaans      hy   Armenian
sq  Albanian       az   Azerbaijani
ar  Arabic         eu   Basque
```

Comment: do you want to print the entries you read in the format you mentioned? I did not understand what you are looking for, but '\t' is tab. print '\t' print a tab char to stdout. hope it is what you are lloking for.

Comment: yes, i just wanna print my stdout like a tab..
but not `'\t'` as you mean...

Comment: what prevents you from using '\t'? you want to read if input has tabs between them?

Comment: so far yet, but I am confused if the data within a certain range, then the next data will be displayed (like tabs)

Comment: have you tried to split with '\t'?
1- line = file.readline()
2- line = line.split('\t')
?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

below is the code that will do what you aim to accomplish, hope it is what you want:

```
f = open('data.txt','r')
lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
l = len(lines)
for i in range(l/2):
    print lines[i]+'\t'+ lines[i + l/2]
if l%2: #if it is odd
    print lines[-1]
```

Comment: Although this produces the correct output, it's incredibly specific to this use case and nearly none of this is reusable.

Answer (score 1):

you can create one list to store your lines per 3 iteration then append this it to `last_q` and at last you can use `zip` function to zip `last_q` and join the pairs with `\t` then write to file again :

```
import copy
q = []
last_q= []
with open('newefile.txt','r') as f:
   for line in f:
        q.append(line.strip())
        if len(q)==3 :
            last_q.append(copy.copy(q))
            q=[]

with open('newefile.txt','w') as f:
    for lines in zip(*last_q) :
        print lines
        f.write('\t'.join(lines)+'\n')
```

Demo :

```
print last_q    
deque([deque(['af  Afrikaans\thy  Armenian', 'sq  Albanian\taz  Azerbaijani', 'ar  Arabic\teu  Basque'], maxlen=3)]) 

print zip(*last_q)
[('af  Afrikaans', 'hy  Armenian'), ('sq  Albanian', 'az  Azerbaijani'), ('ar  Arabic', 'eu  Basque')]
```

Final result :

```
af  Afrikaans   hy  Armenian
sq  Albanian    az  Azerbaijani
ar  Arabic      eu  Basque
```

Comment: I did not lower the vote sir... your answer is correct sir, but I am more able to understand what I consider it right.. :) thank you verry much for your help.. :)

Comment: @agaust yes ,welcome ,but  first , if you find an answer helpful and correct you can tell this to community with voting , also if you are a programmer or want to learn , you need to deal with general and more efficient ways! and refuse to being lazy ;)

Comment: I think you're missing a `]` somewhere in your `deque([` line

Comment: @KasraAD what does making them `deque`s do? Certainly the `maxlen` shouldn't matter, right? Unless I'm just completely not understanding the answer, it seems like lists would do the same job. How is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/baf7b2d0855bc4658923) different from your answer?

Comment: @AdamSmith You are right, fixed! actually at the first i thought about using another way with max len , but after some changes i don't notice about this problem! thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a particular fan of the `itertools` [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe for things like this.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
# in Python2 do:
## from itertools import izip_longest

data = """af  Afrikaans
sq  Albanian
ar  Arabic
hy  Armenian
az  Azerbaijani
eu  Basque""".splitlines()

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

for line in zip(*grouper(data, 3, '')):
    print('\t'.join(line))
```

This can be nicely modular

```
# tablefy.py

from itertools import zip_longest

def rows(data, max_rows=None, columndelimiter="\t"):
    """Produces rows, squeezing extra data into max_rows by
    adding columns delimited by columndelimiter"""
    # rows(['a','b','c','d'], 3, "    ") --> ['a    d', 'b    ', 'c    ']

    if max_rows is None:
        return (row for row in data)

    def _grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
        """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
        # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

    for line in _grouper(data, max_rows, fillvalue=""):
        yield "\t".join(line)
```

```
# my_file.py

data = """af  Afrikaans
sq  Albanian
ar  Arabic
hy  Armenian
az  Azerbaijani
eu  Basque""".splitlines()

import tablefy

for row in tablefy.rows(data, max_rows=3):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Plus because this is a good solution for this problem , but note that its not good for files with long length!!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is actually print two different lines on the same line, separated by a tab. So you would have to read them all and then print them with the tab in the middle. Something like this:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for i in f.readlines():
    lines.append(i.replace("\n", ""))

for i in range(0, len(lines)/2):
   print lines[i] +  "\t" + lines[len(lines)/2 + i]
```

Comment: how if the data is odd?

Comment: If this solution worked, it's because it happened to work in this specific dataset. It's not really the best way to go about the process.

Comment: I omitted the odd-even check to keep it simple but you would actually need to add it.